# WAS Liberty profile - Read property using ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream

Tags: java, classpath, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

We are migrating our application from WAS 6.1 to Liberty. Our application uses third party jars that read property files by`InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("myproperty.properties")`. 
In WAS 6.1, we set server classpath to the location of myproperty.properties. We tried the below approaches to set classpath in Liberty, but nothing works

Approach 1: Set the below in jvm.options (D:\ConfigFiles\DEV\ - path containing myproperty.properties)

```
-Djava.class.path=D:\\ConfigFiles\\DEV\\
```

Approach 2: Setting the classloader in server.xml,

```
<library id="config">
 <folder dir="${server.config.dir}/config/" includes="*.properties" scanInterval="5s"/>
</library>

<enterpriseApplication id="applicationEAR" location="application.ear" name="application">
 <classloader privateLibraryRef="config"/>
</enterpriseApplication>
```

Please let us know if there is any other ways to override/set classpath in Liberty profile?

Comment: Fix the third party lib to use `getResourceAsStream()` method like this: `InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myproperty.properties");`

Comment: Unfortunately we dont have access to the third party source code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting this property in jvm.options (instead of `-Djava.class.path=path/to/propertyDir`):

`-Xbootclasspath/a:path/to/propertyDir`

This will append the path of the property directory (containing your resource file) to the JVM's bootstrap classpath.  Because this is an append, it should also work in Java 9+ (some related options have been removed in Java 9).

I suspect that the reason `-Djava.class.path=...` doesn't work is that the JVM gets the classpath from the WLP server script - so the system property is essentially applied too late in the startup of the server JVM.

You might also be able to put the properties file(s) in your JVM's `lib/ext` directory, but I haven't tested that.  The `-Xbootclasspath/a:path` approach works for me on Mac - I assume it will also work on Windows.

HTH, Andy

Comment: This solved my problem. The property file is read now. Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome - glad to hear that it works for you.  I upvoted @Andy Guibert's answer because it is probably the better long term solution, but this answer works for cases where you don't control the library that loads the resource/class/etc.

Comment: Hi Andy, Just wanted to check if this would work on Linux too ?

Comment: @Bruno yes.  it should work on all platforms, but I have only tested it on Mac with the Oracle Java 8 JDK.

Comment: Will this be a good approach to load lot of properties in JVM directly? Will this not make JVM heavy and impact on performance of whole application? Any different opinion?

Answer (score 2):

If your end goal is to load a properties file, a more straightforward way to do this would be using a bootstrap/env/system property or `<jndiEntry>` in server.xml to store the location of the properties file, and then load it.  For example, using an environment variable:

(in server.xml file)

```
<server>
  <featureManager>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    ...
  </featureManager>

  <jndiEntry jndiName="configDir" value="D:\\ConfigFiles\\Dev"/>    
</server>
```

Then, you can load the resource in your application like this:

```
@Resource(lookup = "configDir")
String configDir;

InputStream is = new FileInputStream(configDir + "/myproperty.properties");
```

Or, if you will always put your config property files somewhere under `${server.config.dir}`, then you can utilize the built-in `SERVER_CONFIG_DIR` environment variable in Liberty:

```
String configDir = System.getenv("SERVER_CONFIG_DIR"); // equivalent to ${server.config.dir} in server.xml
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(configDir + "/myproperty.properties");
```

On the topic of managing configuration, check out MicroProfile Config (e.g. `<feature>microProfile-1.2</feature>`) which you may find useful:
 [Configuring microservices with Liberty](https://openliberty.io/guides/microprofile-config.html)

Comment: Hi @Andy Guibert,

Thank you for the response.
We are not able to implement the above approach because the code snippet `InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("myproperty.properties")`
 is inside a third party jar.

So, is there a way to override the classpath, without the changing the reading logic.